# Adobe Muse shows document.createElement link, but won't preview

Tags: javascript, html, dom, muse

I'm trying to show a link only at certain times of the day.

The link is visible within Adobe Muse, but is hidden on browser.

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var day= new Date();

var hr= day.getUTCHours();


if ((hr == 0) || (hr == 1) || (hr == 2) || (hr == 3) || (hr == 4) || (hr == 5) || (hr == 6) || (hr == 7) || (hr == 8) || (hr == 9) || (hr == 10) || (hr == 11) || (hr == 12) || (hr == 13) || (hr == 22) || (hr == 23)) {   var a = document.createElement('a'); var linkText = document.createTextNode("Example"); a.appendChild(linkText); a.title = "Example"; a.style.fontSize = "16px"; a.style.color="#C31E2F"; a.href = "http://www.example.com/"; document.body.appendChild(a);}

if ((hr == 14) || (hr == 15) || (hr == 16) || (hr == 17) || (hr == 18) || (hr == 19) || (hr == 20) || (hr == 21)) { document.write("<br><font>CALL TOLL FREE:xxx-xxx-xxxx</font></br>");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up trashing most of the existing code.  I think `document.createElement` was causing the problem.

Here's what I'm using instead.

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
var day= new Date();
var hr= day.getUTCHours();
if ((hr>=0 && hr<13) || (hr>=22 && hr<=23)) { 
document.write('<font>Example</font>'.link('http://www.example.com/')); }
else { document.write("<font>CALL TOLL FREE:xxx-xxx-xxxx</font>"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it's hidden? This script is getting time from your device local time. If it's correct, you should get correct result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var day= new Date();
var hr= day.getUTCHours();
if ((hr>=0 && hr<13) || (hr>=22 && hr<=23)) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Example");
    a.appendChild(linkText); a.title = "Example";
    a.style = "font-size: 16px; #C31E2F; color: #C31E2F"; 
    a.href = "http://www.example.com/";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
} else {     
       var out=document.createElement("P");
       out.innerHTML = "<br>CALL TOLL FREE:xxx-xxx-xxxx</br>";
       document.body.appendChild(out);  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why, but the link won't appear on the site in preview or when it's been uploaded.  The code you provided does the same thing.  Maybe it's an issue with my version of muse?

Comment: I've updated the code after `else {` . Check if it works. If not, it must be some other part of code, that is limiting the outcome of this script - outside of the code you provided.